# Inject Custom Sharding in Cassandra or Couchbase

Tags: cassandra, couchbase

Can I inject a sharding algorithm to wither Cassandra or Couchbase?
Or do they decide where each document go to?

For instance if I want to pin data to shards by one of the data properties.

Answer (score 2):

Couchbase hash the key of the document to decide in which shard(vBucket) the document should be associated with. The SDK also uses the same algorithm to find out in which shard the document is located when you want to retrieve the document by its key.

One of the problems of letting developers decide on the sharding algorithm is that sometimes they end up with an excessive number of documents in a single shard, and naturally, this shard becomes the bottleneck of the application.

One of the core concepts in Couchbase is that the documents are (almost) evenly distributed between all shards, so I am not familiar with any native support to insert your own algorithm there.

Comment: This answer is correct, but I just want to add that in Couchbase 5.5, there is a concept of index partitioning, that essentially allows you to define shards for your *indexes* (not the data). This could help performance if you partition based on a field that you also run queries against. (see: https://blog.couchbase.com/index-partitioning-couchbase-server/)

Answer (score 1):

Cassandra decides where the data goes by the partition key. So if you use the data you want to use as the "pin" as the partition key then it will accomplish what your asking for I think. However, you don't pick the replicas explicitly and it can change as hosts are removed and added to the cluster.